# ReactJS - how to get current page in the URL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a menu in my React app, here's the `Menu` component:

```
class Menu extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            active: '/'
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <nav>
            <ul className='list-inline'>
                <li>
                    <Link to='/' style={this.state.active === '/' ? activeStyle : {}} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, '/')}>
                        Home
                    </Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to='/contact' style={this.state.active === 'contact' ? activeStyle : {}} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 'contact')}>
                        Contact
                    </Link>
                </li>
        )
    }
}
export default Menu
```

When I click on a menu item, the clicked item will get higlighted (bold). But if I have in the URL some page (eg. `http://localhost:3001/contact`) and refresh the page, this `Contact` item in the menu will not be highlighted (because highlighting is made based on the `onClick` event).

I tried to parse the content of URL with `import * as qs from 'query-string'; // for fetching the URL paramaters` and then I tried to display the URL content:

```
console.log(qs.parse(location.search));
```

But the output is only `{}` instead of the desired `contact` (so I could highlight this item in the menu).

Thus, when a URL is loaded straight (without click on the respective menu item), how do I catch this situation and highlight the respective menu item?

Thank you

Comment: https://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/IndexLink.html 

This may be another approach? 
Then you can style the link based on its `active` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React router has a component for exactly this situation

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink

You can change the component from `Link` to `NavLink` and add the component will check the url in which you are.

```
<Link to='/contact' style={this.state.active === 'contact' ? activeStyle : {}} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 'contact')}>
  Contact
</Link>


<NavLink
  to="/contact"
  activeStyle={activeStyle}
>Contact</NavLink>
```

Also, you can check the URL params from the router instance:

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params